# Calculating worldFront like in SCNARView

Tags: swift, arkit, core-motion

In `SCNARView` I can access a property of `camera node` called `worldFront`, which represents camera rotation. I would like to calculate similar vector from `CoreMotion` values not using `SCNARView`, just data from `CoreMotion`. So that I can get a vector that would be equal to `worldFront` in `SCNARView` if camera was facing the same direction. Can someone explain me how to calculate such a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer:

```
override var cameraFrontVector: double3 {
    guard let quaternion = motionService.deviceMotion?.attitude.quaternion else { return .zero }

    let x = 2 * -(quaternion.x * quaternion.z + quaternion.w * quaternion.y)
    let z = 2 *  (quaternion.y * quaternion.z - quaternion.w * quaternion.x)
    let y = 2 *  (quaternion.x * quaternion.x + quaternion.y * quaternion.y) - 1

    return double3(x: x, y: y, z: z)
}
```

This gives me values like `worldFront` in `SCNNode`.

Answer (score 0):

The attitude property probably could help

```
func rollCam(motion: CMDeviceMotion) {
    let attitude = motion.attitude
    let roll     = Float(attitude.roll-M_PI/2)
    let yaw      = Float(attitude.yaw)
    let pitch    = Float(attitude.pitch)
    camNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(roll, -yaw, pitch)
}
```

With this piece of code, quite long time ago, I experimented a bit with CoreMotion. I was trying to first detect human walking and then (with the startDeviceMotionUpdates data) move and roll the camera near to an "anchored" SCNBox. Later on ARKit solved my need with the ARAnchor class

What feature are you looking after?

Comment: I'm developing AR framework with few possible engines, one of which is combination of UIView and CoreMotion. I have written a method that calculates a position in world where camera is pointing, but it needs a vector in direction where camera is pointing in local coordinate space. In ARKit engine I can use worldFront of camera node, and it works great, but when I use clear CoreMotion I don't have anything else but CoreMotion data. I need to know the formula to calculate the same values as this worldFront using just CoreMotion attitude or gravity.

Comment: Code you provided doesn't work for my needs, but I'll try to play with it a little. Thanks.

Comment: I think I should somehow rotate vector like double(0, 0, -1) by attitude quaternion, but I can't find out how to do this to get value  equal to worldFront